# CSS Horizontal Scroll with 2 items column

Tags: html, css

I am trying to pass a horizontal scroll for a "2 columns" type container, for 1 column I can use flex easily with this :

```
.slider-wr{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.item{
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

However this does not work for what I intend to, you can check what I currently have in columns here :
http://jsfiddle.net/0wm2cnao/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can use another additional div elements.
Something like this:

```
<div class="slider-wr">

    <div class="package">
        <div class="item">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="package">
        <div class="item">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try wrapping it in another div:

```
<div class="slider-wr-outer">

<div class="slider-wr">
 <div class="item">

 </div>
  <div class="item">

 </div>
  <div class="item">

 </div>
  <div class="item">

 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And then limiting the slider-wr width:

```
.slider-wr{
  min-width: 550px;
}
```

And making the outer div scroll:

```
.slider-wr-outer{
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```